# CSS Custom Properties not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following CSS Custom property set like follows:

```
:root {
  --login-top: 20px;
}
```

In the CSS I use this in the following places:

```
@keyframes loginformstart{
    from {top:200px;}
    to  {top: var(--login-top);}
}

.login_form_hide
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: var(--login-top);
    animation-name: loginformhide;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

This works great in Firefox but not in Chrome. Am I doing something wrong?

Source:[W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility), Firefox is the only browser that currently supports css variables.

Comment: So using this would be risky with the assumption that other browsers will soon adapt?

Comment: @K3NN3TH it isn't risky - it just won't work on every browser except FF. I'd recommend you that you use some CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) if you wan't to work with variables.

Comment: @K3NN3TH if you care about backward compatiblity then don't use them