# CSS Custom properties not working with Google Chrome 67.0

Tags: html, css

I have seen via this question:

[CSS Custom Properties not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385349/css-custom-properties-not-working-in-chrome)

That CSS custom properties weren't implemented until 49.0 while trying to implement and use custom properties with 67.0, I am getting  a 'Invalid property value' against the background-color in the Google Developer tool.

CSS:

From my understanding you set the custom property such as:

```
:root{
    --PrimaryColour: #71b220;
}
```

And then apply it such as:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading{
    background-color: var(--PrimaryColour);
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2015 and it just doesn't seem to work. Is there something I am missing here?

EDIT: In Google Developer it appears as

```
background-colour: --PrimaryColour
```

However if i (in Google Developer) edit it so it is:

```
background-colour: var(--PrimaryColour);
```

it seems to work. The prefix of 'var' seems to be getting ommitted.

Comment: it works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/2w0nohdL/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Have you got any ideas on why it would not be applied for me even after clearing cache?

Comment: I don't know if that is the cause for any of your problems, but you have two different spellings of "color/colour" in your code examples...

Comment: @Johannes No, that wasn't the issue, the issue was random behaviour from Visual Studio by the looks of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found. Strange behaviour from Visual Studio. It kept omitting the prefix 'var' from the css. After a couple of rebuilds it began to stop and show custom properties correctly.